# How to include Fnv_hash<>::hash c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am migrating a c++98 code base to a c++ 11/14. One of the libraries used by my project is using the following function to calculate the hash of a string.

```
std::tr1::Fnv_hash<>::hash
```

Apparently, the std::namespace in c++11 doesn't contain this function anymore. Even though I can change the code of the external library, I don't want to as it requires a significant amount of work and time.

how can I include thi specific function in my project when compiling with std=c++11?

I tried to use gnu++11 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There was no standard function `Fnv_hash`, it's just `libstdc++` specific function. You can look at the definition [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/tr1_2functional-source.html#l01141). You can include `"tr1/functional_hash.h"` and continue to use it.

Comment: so, this function has been removed from the lisstdc++ used for c++11?

Comment: @GiuseppePes no, at least in gcc 5.3 there is header tr1/functional_hash. But, there is no such function in standard c++.

Comment: sorry for my ingnorance, but what's the difference between standard c++ and libstdc++? I thought that libstdc++ is the lib that implements all c++ standard functions?

Comment: @GiuseppePes yes, but libstdc++ can contain different help function, used internally in libstdc++ and so on, code from your library use such function.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. So I tried to include <tr1/functional_hash.h> but it didn't work

Comment: @GiuseppePes so... then just rewrite use of this function in library.